# Copy File With PHP By copy() function so slow

Tags: php, function, copy

I use windows 7 ultimate and xampp in my computer. I use `copy()` function to copy file with PHP. But, When I tested it with same device and same file, copy function from Windows Explorer Faster than when I copy file with php by `copy()` function.

(525MB take about 5minutes with Windows Explorer and 25Minutes With PHP, my files located in HTDOCS folder. And the destination is Flashdisk).

Is there anyway to make `copy()` function in php more fast? Or maybe is there any other function to copy file in php that run faster?

Thank you anyway.

Comment: It takes several minutes to copy a 525MB file? That's annoyingly slow, should be done in a matter of seconds. Are we talking about creating a local copy or are you transfering the file to a remote host?

Comment: We Talking about creating local copy. Is it function software issue? Or may be a hardware?

Comment: If windows is only able to copy about 100MB per minute then it sounds like a hardware problem to me. On my PC which is not a high end machine 500MB are copied in less then 10 seconds which would be about 3GB/minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have tested it Manytimes, And I get That's Hardware Solution. Although, Yes! php copy function slower than explorer. I think because it call by function in function to check is object file or folder.

SIMACO : Copy by My Program
Windows Explorer : Copy by File Explorer Windows

[image]